# source of a ToExpression::sntxi error when running Install[]

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I have been getting an "ToExpression::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed" error when trying to `Install[]` a new WSTP program I've written. It's entirely possible that there is some problem with the WSTP program, but this error doesn't give me a clue what it might be. I haven't even called the program yet, merely tried to `Install[]` it. Is there a WSTP or Install[] guru who might be able to suggest the circumstances under which running `Install[]` can produce such an odd error? For the record, a WSTP program *does* end up running, though unusable as it has returned only `$Failed` to the kernel.

Other WSTP programs install and run just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MathLink [template file](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/file.tm.html) has Mathematica code in it.  Almost certainly your template file has code with syntax errors.  "Incomplete expression" indicates that you may have forgotten to close a bracket.

If you can't find the error, please post the template file.

Comment: I will look into this when I get to the office, but your suggestion surprises me -- I compile my .tm file into C++ and include it in my build. Does Mathematica code survive that process?

Comment: @MichaelStern Yes. You can check in the produced C file. It is partly this Mathematica code that sets up definitions when `Install` is run. It is also allowed to put arbitrary M code in the .tm file, which will be run on `Install[]`.

Comment: I found several potential problems in the template, the proximate one almost certainly being a missing quotation mark. Thanks a million for this answer.